# apoc.cypher.run subquery same result for all nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

please i hope you can help me with this query

```
MATCH
(user:users)-[watch:WATCH]->(m:Movies)
where
 m.genre = 2 and
 watch.date >= date({year: 2020, month: 06, day: 01}) 
 CALL apoc.cypher.run('
    with $m as m
    MATCH (m)<-[watches_too:WATCH]-(user2:users)-[:WATCH]->(m2:Movies)
    WHERE
        m2.duration > 50 and
        m2.genre = 2 and
        m.id <> m2.id and
        m.subgenre = m2.subgenre and
        watches_too.date>= date({year: 2020, month: 06, day: 01})
    RETURN m2, count(m2.id) as ocurrences
    ORDER by ocurrences DESC
    LIMIT 4',
    {m:m}) YIELD value
RETURN
 user.id, value.m2.id;
```

The query "works" mostly as I wanted, gives me movies other users watched that also watched the movie of the first user, limiting to 4 results per user, but I noticed it gives me the same 4 movies for all users...

am I doing something wrong or is it really those 4 movies the most watched per that genre?

Comment: Something to do with your graph data?

Comment: I left the query running for all users and it does indeed throw different results, so it seems that the query was ok, only that many users watched the same movie.

still, the query was way too heavy and takes a lot of time.. any chance i can use apoc.cypher.parallelmap besides apoc.cypher.run?

Comment: You might think of some sort of preprocessing and store similar relationships between movies, so you don't have to traverse half the graph for each recommendation